# Author of the short story "Owls"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the author of a short story called *Owls* which I read in a sci fi magazine in the 80s. It was about 2 travelers driving through a forest at night and seeing a caution sign that says owls.

The story has these 2 travelers driving through wooded area and passed a caution sign that says owls. Because it seemed odd for there to be a caution sign that says owls the men stop to examine the sign. Now this is happening at night. Both men get out of car and while the man that noticed the sign examines and discovers the sign really does say owls the disbeliever is swept up into the air. As he raises his flash light to see what has him he sees a claw and wing right before he drops the flashlight.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! you may want to look at the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/); it has suggestions on additional information that may help you think of additional facts you can add to your question to help us help you!

Comment: Found A short story from 1975 by Vince Aandahl called "Owls" but can't find a synopsis. You may be able to find the magazine scanned somewhere (Internet Archive search is down right now). http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50717

Comment: I think we need more information. The only story titled "Owls" published in the 80s or earlier is Vance Aandahl's "Owls" in the July 1975 F&SF, and the story doesn't match.  It's an odd story taking place on the Navajo reservation with a man seeking the source of drumming at night and finding an oil derrick...and owls.  Very odd.

Comment: Not to mention the stories called "Owl" rather than Owls; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&OPERATOR_1=exact&TERM_1=owl&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=exact&TERM_2=&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=exact&TERM_3=&ORDERBY=title_title&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: I could be wrong on the title then....the story has these 2 travelers driving through wooded area and pass a caution sign that says owls...because it seemed odd for there to be a caution sign that says owls the men stop to examine the sign...now this is happening at night .. Both men get out of car and while the man that noticed the sign exams and discovers the sign really does say owls the disbeliver is swept up into the air...as he raises his flash light to see what has him he sees a claw and wing right before he drops the flashlight...this was a short story....any help would be great

Answer (score 10):

#### [Caution Sign](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49290) by Brad Strickland

> Joan and Hal are fighting. Now it's about the caution sign that Joan
> insists said O-W-L-S and Hal thinks must have said slow.
>
> <sup>[sfbookreview.blogspot.com](http://sfbookreview.blogspot.com/2018/05/may-1988-fantasy-science-fiction.html)</sup>

Excerpt:

> "Where are you?" he shouted. "Damn it — "  He thought for a second he
> was having a heart attack. That's how they said it felt: knife-sharp
> pain gripping the shoulders, a sensation of floating. Then he realized
> he was floating. Thin tree branches flailed him, fell away. Hot blood
> oozed over the skin inside his coat and shirt, flowed in rivulets down
> his back and chest. He wheezed for breath. Wildly, he tried to turn
> the light upward, to see what had him, to glimpse the talons that had
> seized him, but the back of his head was wedged against a feathered
> keel as tough and flexible as spring steel. He felt muscles working
> above him, felt felt rhythmic gusts of wind, like air displaced by
> great, silent wings. The flashlight dropped from his numbing right
> hand.

Comment: Edited the quote just to make it a bit clearer for what quote the source is referring too.

Comment: Good find. The whole story is available at https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v074n05_1988-05_LennyS-aMouse/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v074n05_1988-05_LennyS-aMouse#page/n87/mode/2up